# Lenovo Thinkpad External Monitor Issue

Tags: release-juno, display, monitors

I'm running the latest eOs Juno with all the latest updates. Unfortunately upon restarting my laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad T460P) the external monitor stopped working and I'm unable to figure out how to fix it.

So far I have done the following

- -deleted the ~/.config/monitor.xml and monitor.xml~ files.
- -restarted my laptop
- plugged out and plugged in my HDMI cable
- started up eOS with the HDMI cable not plugged in
- power cycled the laptop
- tested different monitors (will test more soon)

The strangest thing was that it was working fine before a restart.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the windows key logo + L (locking the screen) resolved my issue. I'm leaving this here in case it helps others.

Update: My issue has returned and locking the screen no longer resolves my issue.

Update 2: Locking the screen resolved my issue again after waiting an hour and just using the computer normally. I'm sure it'll happen again, so I'll continue to provide feedback. I went through the same troubleshooting steps as I had done previously.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issues with or without external monitor - HP Pavilion computer.
All the solutions(?) I already found was until the next day, or restart or whatever situation happens.. The last one I found and it works for now is the script from there 
https://gist.github.com/RyanMillerC/c48d9f63f8fe386b22a7da18cf6913d2

it is important if you try it to make the script executable
 `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/set-primary-monitor-pantheon-greeter`

read the comments there for more information.